# How can I set a variable in python on button press

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I would like to stop a loop with a button press in python on my raspberry pi.

I came with this code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(14, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(2,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(21,GPIO.IN)
break_prog=False

def key_press(key):
   print("BREAK")
   break_prog=True

GPIO.add_event_detect(21,GPIO.FALLING,callback=key_press,bouncetime=300)

for i in range(5):
    if break_prog:
       print("STOP THE LOOP")
       break
    else:
       print("VERT")
       GPIO.output(2,True)
       GPIO.output(14,False)
       time.sleep(3)
       print("ROUGE")
       GPIO.output(2,False)
       GPIO.output(14,True)   
       time.sleep(6)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

When I press the button, 'BREAK' text clearly appears, but in my loop, the if break_prog part is not called, like the variable hasn't been set.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: add `global break_prog` before `print("BREAK")`. Also use a mutex

Comment: Every function in Python has its own variable namespace. To assign to the global namespace you have to use `global break_prog` in the function first.

Comment: BTW in Python you always have to call functions and methods explicitly: `GPIO.cleanup` → `GPIO.cleanup()`

Comment: Global indeed fixed the issue. Thanks.